# CakePHP table sorting with bootstrap icons

Tags: cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

I want to sort a table by `id` when clicking on it. It is working but the main thing is that the bootstrap arrow up and down icons should also be attached to the `id` label.

When the data is displayed in descending order, then the bootstrap `arrow-bottom` icon should be shown, and when the data is displayed in ascending order, then the `arrow-up` icon should be shown.

**UsersController.php**

```
 public $paginate = array('limit'=>4);

 public function index() {
      $this->User->recursive = 0;
      $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
 }
```

**index.ctp**

```
<div class="users index">
<h2><?php echo __('Users'); ?></h2>

<table class="zebra-striped table-bordered " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
        <th>
            <a href='' >
                <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id'); ?>
                 <i class='icon-arrow-up'></i>
            </a> 
        </th>
        <th><a href='' >First Name <i class='icon-arrow-down'></i>
       </a>   </th>
        <th>Last Name <i class='icon-resize-full'></i></a></th>

</tr>
    <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo h($user['User']['id']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo h($user['User']['first_name']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo h($user['User']['last_name']); ?>&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<p>
<?php
     echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
       'format' => __('Page {:page} of {:pages}, showing {:current} records out of {:count} total, starting on record {:start}, ending on {:end}')
));
 ?> </p>

<div>

     <div class="pagination">
<ul>

     <?php

             echo $this->Paginator->prev(__('prev'), array('tag' => 'li'),
           null, array('tag' => 'li','class' => 'disabled','disabledTag' => 'a'));
            echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '','currentTag' 
            => 'a', 'currentClass' => 'active','tag' => 'li','first' => 1));
            echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next'), array('tag' => 'li','currentClass' => 'disabled'), null, array('tag' => 'li','class' => 'disabled','disabledTag' => 'a'));
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please always mention the exact CakePHP version your are using!

Answer (score 9):

A Simple Solution using Jquery, just add the below 3 lines in your default application.js or in layout/default.ctp

```
$('th a').append(' <i class="icon-sort"></i>');
$('th a.asc i').attr('class', 'icon-sort-down');
$('th a.desc i').attr('class', 'icon-sort-up');
```

Another Simple CSS Based Solution, Include Font Awesome's necessary files.

```
th > a:after {
    content: " \f0dc";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
th > a.asc:after {
    content: " \f0dd";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
th > a.desc:after {
    content: " \f0de";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Comment: The Simple CSS Based Solution is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`PaginatorHelper::sortDir()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper%3a%3asortDir) to check the current sort direction and build the class name based on that value:

```
<i class='icon-arrow-<?php echo $this->Paginator->sortDir() === 'asc' ? 'up' : 'down'; ?>'></i>
```

To embed this into a sort link, pass the HTML as the second parameter to [`PaginatorHelper::sort()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper%3a%3asort), and set the `escape` option to false:

```
$type = $this->Paginator->sortDir() === 'asc' ? 'up' : 'down';
$icon = "<i class='icon-arrow-" . $type . "'></i>";
echo $this->Paginator->sort('id', $icon, array('escape' => false));
```

That should result in a link like:

```
<a href="/.../page:1/sort:id/direction:asc/"><i class='icon-arrow-up'></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need also check a key, so it would be

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('title', 'My great title'); ?> 
<?php if ($this->Paginator->sortKey() == 'title'): ?>
    <i class='fa fa-sort-<?php echo $this->Paginator->sortDir() === 'asc' ? 'up' : 'down'; ?>'></i>
<?php else: ?>
    <i class='fa fa-sort'></i>
<?php endif; ?>
```